# Particles inside a moving Box2d world are getting drawn on top instead of inside a layer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using LevelHelper to build my level, and I'm adding some particles (dynamically initialized CCParticleSystemQuad's) inside my level. All works fine until I move the world (it's a dynamically drawn world in Box2D in which I follow the player with the camera). If I move the world, newly added particles,which are emitting continuously, are drawn at the right position but in the particle-animation afterwards the particles seem to be drawn relatively of the global world/screen position. This gives a weird 'trippy' effect which looks totally unrealistic. The particles should be redrawn/refreshed inside the world

```
LevelHelperLoader * lh = gameLayer.lh;
LHLayer * layer = [lh layerWithUniqueName:@"MAIN_LAYER"];

NSArray * array = [lh spritesWithTag:WORTEL];
CCParticleSystemQuad * particle;
CGPoint position;
for (LHSprite * sprite in array) {
    particle = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"DirtParticles.plist"];
    [layer addChild:particle z:0];
    position = sprite.position;
    position.y += sprite.contentSize.height * 0.5f;
    [particle setPosition:position];
    [particle resetSystem];
}
```

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the particle position type:

```
particle.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
```

The alternatives are kCCPositionTypeRelative and kCCPositionTypeGrouped. You may have to try all to see which of them best fits your scenario, I'm guessing it's either "free" or "relative".

Comment: "relative" it is. Thank's a lot! Sorry I couldn't give you more 'loot' ;)